upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 fails with error message
I cant upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 i get this error message.
W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., W:GPG error: http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32, E:The repository 'http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' is not signed., W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details., W:GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32, E:The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease' is not signed.
Please help. i am a complete newbe with linux

"bionic" repopsitories are very much older than 22.04 (jammy).  You should at least remove the old lines in /etc/apt/sources.list, and check /etc/apt/sources.list.d for old files.Then update/upgrade to a clean 22.04 system before trying upgrade to 24.04

How do I do that? Can someone give me the terminal text?

This question is similar to: How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: How do I fix the GPG error "NO_PUBKEY"?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
